# Dublin to Belfast by bus. Where do I get my passport stamped

Tags: us-citizens, ireland, passport-stamps, northern-ireland, common-travel-area

I'm an American, traveling from Dublin to Belfast by bus. Where do I get my passport stamped to prove that I have left Ireland (I will have stayed 90 days here) and to show the beginning date for my UK stay (hoping to stay 3 months) Thanks all

Comment: See this related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr

Comment: Jason do you have any advice for me. Do you think they may grant me an extention because of my mistake, I have already finalized all my travel plans through the UK.

Comment: Extension of your Irish visitor permission is possible in extreme unforeseen circumstances, but unlikely in your case as extensions are not given simply to allow the applicant to continue tourist activities http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Extension%20of%20Visitor%20Permission%20in%20the%20State

Comment: @Tenzin Tharpa I’m struggling to think of any option other than you leaving the CTA for a nearby European destination (that’s not the UK), spending a few days there and then resuming your itinerary by travelling direct to the UK. It might look like a visa run to Immigration but your citizenship is in your favour and presumably you have paperwork to prove you can support yourself without working illegally and have a plan to leave.

Comment: My plan was to spend 2 months in the UK and then take the tube to Paris to begin my Schengen visa. If I overstay my visa will they check me coming off the tube in Paris?

Comment: @Tenzin Tharpa As a US citizen you don’t need, and won’t be given, a Schengen visa to enter as a tourist. What you will have is visa-free entry for a period of up to 90 out of 180 days. If you’re planning to go to Paris via the Tunnel, you will go through exit controls in London. At which point I’d assume your CTA overstay would be noticed.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. One last question, I would like to stay legal, so I'm thinking of flying to Paris for the weekend and then re-entering on the tube from Paris to London. is this a good idea?

Comment: @TenzinTharpa Just a small note, but you might confuse people if you call the channel tunnel "the tube". The tube is the underground railway in London. I've never heard anyone call the channel tunnel "the tube".

Comment: @tenzin yes that is a very good idea

Comment: One last thought. Does the common travel area, have the 90 days in and 90 days out (within a 180 day period) policy?

Comment: @TenzinTharpa No. UK border officers use their judgement as to whether you're spending too much time visiting the UK. The rule of thumb is that you certainly shouldn't exceed more than six months in the last year, but your leave could be limited to significantly less than this, depending on your personal circumstances, and the answers you give to the border officer at entry.

Answer (score 15):

You actually **cannot travel to the UK** after spending 90 days in Ireland.  The 90 days is for the whole common travel area, not just the Republic of Ireland!

The UK and Republic of Ireland form part of the common travel area
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area

This means that there are no border checks, immigration, or customs between the two countries so there is no possibility to get your passport stamped as proof.  Therefore, the 90 days stay which you were allowed when you entered the Republic of Ireland applies to the whole common travel area, not just the Republic.

This post describes in more details for different circumstances.

[Implications in crossing the Ireland/Northern Ireland land border for an American](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68718/implications-in-crossing-the-ireland-northern-ireland-land-border-for-an-america)

FYI regarding cross border travel:  It is generally accepted that you need to retain your own proof of travel between the countries.  This means boarding passes, ferry tickets, train tickets, bus tickets etc. that prove your travel.  This should be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: It is very important to note this was written on September 9, 2019. Whether this is valid in two months and later, _noone knows_.

Comment: @chx On the  contrary,  the basic rules for the **Common Travel Area** is probably the only aspect that we can be sure of not changing. There has been agreement, from all sides, since day one of this affair.

Comment: I find your <del>lack of</del> faith disturbing.

Comment: @chx As a 13 year old boy in Ireland in 1968/69 we had faith that the problems then would blow over. Reality taught us otherwise in the later years. My hope (faith) is that **common sense** will prevail after the reality of the present situation sinks in.

Comment: @chx Just as several non-EU countries are part of the Schengen area (a collaboration for common immigration control just as the CTA), there are no inherent reasons why the CTA can't remain exactly as it works today even if UK leaves the EU. Brexit is complicated enough, even if you don't invent or predict totally imaginary problems.